# Should I be worried about "warning: checksum areas are greater than image size. Invalid section table?" messages during kernel upgrade?

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, kernel, checksums

I just ran the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and this was the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-headers-4.2.0-23 linux-headers-4.2.0-23-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.2.0-23-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
  linux-signed-generic linux-signed-image-generic
6 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 67.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 287 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic amd64 4.2.0-23.28 [17.3 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic amd64 4.2.0-23.28 [38.6 MB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-generic amd64 4.2.0.23.25 [1,784 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-image-generic amd64 4.2.0.23.25 [2,418 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-signed-image-4.2.0-23-generic amd64 4.2.0-23.28 [3,998 B]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-signed-generic amd64 4.2.0.23.25 [1,816 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-signed-image-generic amd64 4.2.0.23.25 [2,456 B]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-headers-4.2.0-23 all 4.2.0-23.28 [9,595 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-headers-4.2.0-23-generic amd64 4.2.0-23.28 [765 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-headers-generic amd64 4.2.0.23.25 [2,390 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 4.2.0-23.28 [817 kB]
Fetched 67.1 MB in 1min 34s (708 kB/s)                                         
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic.
(Reading database ... 356003 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic_4.2.0-23.28_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic_4.2.0-23.28_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_4.2.0.23.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.2.0.23.25) over (4.2.0.22.24) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.2.0.23.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.2.0.23.25) over (4.2.0.22.24) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-signed-image-4.2.0-23-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-signed-image-4.2.0-23-generic_4.2.0-23.28_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-image-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-signed-generic_4.2.0.23.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-generic (4.2.0.23.25) over (4.2.0.22.24) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-signed-image-generic_4.2.0.23.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-image-generic (4.2.0.23.25) over (4.2.0.22.24) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.2.0-23.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.2.0-23_4.2.0-23.28_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.2.0-23 (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.2.0-23-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.2.0-23-generic_4.2.0-23.28_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.2.0.23.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.2.0.23.25) over (4.2.0.22.24) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_4.2.0-23.28_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.2.0-23.28) over (4.2.0-22.27) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-21-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-21-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.2.0.23.25) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.2.0-23 (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.2.0.23.25) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.2.0.23.25) ...
Setting up linux-signed-image-4.2.0-23-generic (4.2.0-23.28) ...
warning: file-aligned section .text extends beyond end of file
warning: checksum areas are greater than image size. Invalid section table?
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-21-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up linux-signed-image-generic (4.2.0.23.25) ...
Setting up linux-signed-generic (4.2.0.23.25) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.2.0-23.28) ...
```

You may notice that some of the lines read:

```
warning: file-aligned section .text extends beyond end of file
warning: checksum areas are greater than image size. Invalid section table?
```

What exactly does this mean and is this anything that I should be worried about?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a page http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html which mentions this warning:

> [...]
>
> ```
> warning: file-aligned section .text extends beyond end of file
> warning: checksum areas are greater than image size. Invalid section table?
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> This example shows two warnings. I don't claim to fully understand them, but they don't seem to do any harm—at least, the Linux kernel binaries I've signed that have produced these warnings have worked fine. (Such warnings seem to be less common in 2015 than they were a couple of years ago.).
>
> [...]

If this author is not worried, then I am neither.

Comment: +1. Notice also that the author is a Canonical employee and [is registered on this site](http://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith), and often gives authoritative answers around the same topics addressed in the page.

Comment: Maybe we should summon @rod-smith then.

Comment: Nevertheless, I still would like an answer which tells me what they actually mean, I mean, someone must understand them for someone wrote them.