# How to remove PlayOnLinux? (Ubuntu Software uninstall doesn't work)

Tags: 18.04, software-center, uninstall, playonlinux, software-uninstall

I go to Ubuntu Software, search for `playonlinux` and then click `remove`:

[image]

It does this...
[image]

An then still shows me it is installed. Also after restart and waiting for 10 hours.
[image]

What can I do?

Does Canonical plan to provide a normal working Software install / uninstall utility in 2018/2019? Does anybody know if something like this is on their roadmap? Can I see the roadmap somewhere?

**UPDATE:**

When doing `sudo apt remove playonlinux`, the following thing happens:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'playonlinux' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-dejavu gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  icoutils libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  libasyncns0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.65-dev
  libboost-regex1.65.1 libboost1.65-dev libbsd0:i386 libcairo2:i386
  libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcups2:i386
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386
  libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgconf2-4 libgd3:i386 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libglx0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtkglext1 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu60:i386 libidn2-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjemalloc1 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  libllvm6.0:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libnettle6:i386 libodbc1
  libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386
  libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libpq5
  libpulse0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsane1:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libsensors4:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio6.1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386
  libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386
  libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
  libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386
  libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxslt1.1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-36-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic
  postgresql-client postgresql-client-10 postgresql-client-common
  python-meld3 python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion python3-netifaces redis-tools
  supervisor wine-stable wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386:i386
  winehq-stable
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.7) ...
warning: file-aligned section .text extends beyond end of file
warning: checksum areas are greater than image size. Invalid section table?
E: Your kernels are unsigned. This system will fail to boot in a secure boot environment.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package grub-pc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: In a terminal, do `sudo apt remove playonlinux` and tell us what happens.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I have updated my question

Comment: Well, it seems that there is quite a bit wrong with your system. Removing `playonlinux` *might* mess it up even more, so that is why nothing happens. You may need to remove an unsigned kernel first. About the unsigned kernel error, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068603/your-kernels-are-unsigned-this-system-will-fail-to-boot-in-a-secure-boot-enviro). The `grub` warnings don't seem to matter much, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717339/should-i-be-worried-about-warning-checksum-areas-are-greater-than-image-size).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is an attempt based on your output. At the outset run,

`sudo apt autoremove`

This generally removes all the obsolete packages that are no longer required. Next, as it seems, you are using an unsigned kernel. You should prefer using a LTS kernel. The latest LTS kernel is 4.19. (See [here](https://www.kernel.org/) for releases). If you want to know how to install/upgrade linux kernels, you can see [this](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/). It is however advisable to stick to the default kernel shipped with the Ubuntu version you are using or the LTS releases. Next, as the throwup suggests, PlayonLinux is not installed. It might have been removed when you uninstalled it from the software center.

Note: Synaptic Package Manager is also a great tool to clear the mess you are facing. It can help you insall upgrades, fix dependency issues and much more. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto).

Comment: I am already running kernel `4.19`, I have installed it with `ukuu`